# Why is artificial gravity not included on space stations?

Tags: iss, gravity, microgravity, space-station, artificial-gravity

I'm wondering why artificial gravity is not included on the ISS, or on the currently planned [OPSEK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_Piloted_Assembly_and_Experiment_Complex).

There are long-term health effects of weightlessness, which would be avoided, using artificial gravity based on centripetal force.